# Problem with NSScanner in the IB connections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, connection, nsscanner

This maybe a silly question, but I am having a problem with the NSScanner.  I have a UITextField in which the text needs to be taken.  I cannot seem to get the NSScanner field connected in Interface Builder.  Can you please help?

My file has the following code:

```
- (IBAction)getUserPassword:(NSScanner *)sender {
    NSCharacterSet *theCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+<>?,./:\";'[]\{}| "];
    [userEntered scanCharactersFromSet:theCharacterSet intoString:&temp];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to connect NSScanner like a UI object. NSScanner isn't a UI object. Did you mean this instead?

```
- (IBAction)getUserPassword:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSScanner *userEntered = [NSScanner scannerWithString:textField.text];
    NSString *temp = nil;
    NSCharacterSet *theCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+<>?,./:\";'[]\{}| "];
    [userEntered scanCharactersFromSet:theCharacterSet intoString:&temp];
    ...
}
```